# How can I prefetch_related across a reverse one-to-one relationship where the one-to-one relationship may be different?

Tags: python, sql, django

Let's say I have a database with Movies, Books, and Software, and they all inherit a single Item model.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    ...

class Movie(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item)
    ...

class Book(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item)
    ...

class Software(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item)
    ...
```

Now I want to make a database query on Item but I want to pick up the related object to that item, whether it be a Movie, Book, or Software.  If all the items were one type, say, Movies, then I could do the following:

```
Item.objects.prefetch_related('movie')
```

However, I need to be able to fetch the related object no matter what type it is.  Can I run:

```
Item.objects.prefetch_related('movie', 'book', 'software')
```

Will this find the related object no matter what type it is, and will this be efficient?  Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll suppose the `OneToOneField`s have `related_name` set as your QuerySet examples indicate, that is, `'movie'`, `'book'` and `'software'` respectively.

To traverse a one-to-one relationship backwards you don't need `prefetch_related`, this is something that is easy to achieve with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` automatically generated by `select_related`. That means, you should be able to do

```
Item.objects.select_related('movie', 'book', 'software')
```

and each returned Item instance will automatically contain a cached instance of the corresponding `Movie`, `Book` and `Software` (if there is one, of course).

`prefetch_related` is only needed when you want to avoid an O(N) query issue with many-to-many or many-to-one relationships, that is, with a `ManyToManyField` or a reverse traversal of `ForeignKey`.